# Need to Delete Blank Row including All Data in the Row - Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: worksheet-function, macbook, macros, microsoft-excel-2011

I have an Excel spreadsheet of email addresses with first and last names. Some of the names do not have an email address and it's blank so I want to delete the blank fields along with the first and last name in that row. I know how to delete all blank fields, but that doesn't delete the entire row as well if there's content in it. The list is about 14K users, so searching/deleting individual rows would be tedious. I'm guessing I need to create a specific macro for it?

I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac.

Any thoughts or tips greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Amar

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the entire dataset using the email column. All rows with that column as blank should then appear together making it easy to manually delete the all the rows at once.